# underscore/lodash merge arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

Hello can someone help.

Have some arrays of grades with classes attributes like these two below:

```
var arr1 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Class 1A AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Class 1B AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Class BG1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 54,
    "name": "Grade 2 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Class AA1 ppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Class BA1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];
```

and

```
var arr2 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Class BB1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];
```

All I want is to merge them into single array of grades with unique classes for each grade.id like the one below:

```
var merge = [
        {
            "id": 53,
            "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
            "classes": [{
                "id": 54,
                "name": "Class 1A AppMonkeyzTest"
            }, {
                "id": 55,
                "name": "Class 1B AppMonkeyzTest"
            }, {
                "id": 59,
                "name": "Class BG1 AppMonkeyzTest"
            }, {
                "id": 58,
                "name": "Class BB1 AppMonkeyzTest"
            }]
        },
        {
            "id": 54,
            "name": "Grade 2 AppMonkeyzTest",
            "classes": [{
                "id": 56,
                "name": "Class AA1 ppMonkeyzTest"
            }, {
                "id": 57,
                "name": "Class BA1 AppMonkeyzTest"
            }]
        }];
```

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @gillesc struggled in vain with underscore. It's really ugly but thanks to all of you guyz have many solutions. +1 for Alexander with _.merge in lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`_.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) with callback, like so

```js
var arr1 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Class 1A AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Class 1B AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Class BG1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 54,
    "name": "Grade 2 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Class AA1 ppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Class BA1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];

var arr2 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Class BB1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];

var res = _.merge(arr1, arr2, function (a, b) {
    if (_.isArray(a)) {
        return a.concat(b);
    }
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.9.3/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS

```
var arr1 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 54,
        "name": "Class 1A AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 55,
        "name": "Class 1B AppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Class BG1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 54,
    "name": "Grade 2 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Class AA1 ppMonkeyzTest"
    }, {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Class BA1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];
var arr2 = [{
    "id": 53,
    "name": "Grade 1 AppMonkeyzTest",
    "classes": [{
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Class BB1 AppMonkeyzTest"
    }]
}];
var arr3 = [];
for (var i in arr1) {
    arr3.push(arr1[i]);
    for (var j in arr2) {
        if (arr2[j].id == arr1[i].id) {
            for (var k in arr2[j].classes) {
                arr3[i].classes.push(arr2[j].classes[k]);
            }

        }
    }

}
console.log(arr3);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qt8eoaw3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use     `_.findIndex()`:

```
var merge = [];

arr1.forEach(function(object){
    var i = _.findIndex(merge, { id: object.id });
    if(i){
        merge[i].classes = merge[i].classes.concat(object.classes)
    }else{
        merge.push(object);
    }
});

arr2.forEach(function(object){
    var i = _.findIndex(merge, { id: object.id });
    if(i){
        merge[i].classes = merge[i].classes.concat(object.classes)
    }else{
        merge.push(object);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, did not refresh when the accepted answer got posted. This looks like a more clear and concise way to do it.